# Handle any event on jQuery datepicker element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-events

I have am using a datepicker and on 'change' event I am formatting the date of model with moment.

```
jQuery('#issued').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true
            }).on('change', (event) => {
                console.dir(event);
                this.issue_at = moment(Date.parse(event.target.value)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
            });
```

This works well when I select a date from calendar but  when I open calendar and click outside it falls back to original date format. I understand I can prevent this if I know what event it triggers when I not select a date.

What is the event name of open calendar but not selecting a date. Even better, how to write a jquery event handler that can handle any event. If not possible, then how do I detect not select date event?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle/CodePen?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "**blur**" or "**focusout**" instead of "**change**" event. As asked by @user7290573 Can you share a jsFiddle just to make sure everything is working as expected.

**Note**: This is actually not the cleanest way possible and will result in firing of the event handler function you have created a lot more than intended.

**EDIT**

If the expected result is to make sure the date is displayed in **YYYY-MM-DD** format you can probably use the following code instead for initialization:

```
jQuery('#issued').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"});
```

Corresponding [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nects896/12/)